# Hibernate: @UniqueConstraint in superclass mapping to subclass

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, unique-constraint, jpa

Java EE 7,
Hibernate 5.4.21.Final

Why does the `SubClass` inherit the `SuperClass` `@UniqueConstraint` annotations, or more specifically why does Hibernate use `SuperClass` annotations during `SubClass` table mapping?

How do I override `@UniqueConstraint` in subclasses?

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table( name = "supTable",
        uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(  name = "UK_multi_col",
                                columnNames = {"colOne", "colTwo"})
        }
)
public class SuperClass implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "colOne")
    protected Long colOne;

    @Column(name = "colTwo")
    protected Long colTwo;
    ...
}
```

using the same name `"UK_multi_col"` in `@UniqueConstraint` does not override in `SubClass` and generates two UNIQUE KEYs in `SubClass` tables. One unique key is from the `SuperClass` and one from `SubClass`, where there should only be one (not including the primary key).

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "subTable",
        uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(  name = "UK_multi_col",
                                columnNames = {"colOne", "colTwo", "colThree"})
        }
)
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    @Column(name = "colThree")
    protected Long colThree;
    ...
}
```

Hibernate generated code:

```
create table test_subTable (
   id bigint not null,
    colOne bigint,
    colTwo bigint,
    colThree bigint,
    primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB

create table test_supTable (
   id bigint not null,
    colOne bigint,
    colTwo bigint,
    primary key (id)
) engine=InnoDB

alter table test_subTable
    drop index UK_multi_col    
alter table test_subTable
    add constraint UK_multi_col unique (colOne, colTwo, colThree)
```

next four lines is code generated by `SuperClass` annotations during `SubClass` mapping:

```
alter table test_subTable
    drop index UK_a5tjgjgpmww7otw30iyvmym1m    
alter table test_subTable
    add constraint UK_a5tjgjgpmww7otw30iyvmym1m unique (colOne, colTwo)
```

continued hibernate generated code:

```
alter table test_supTable
    drop index UK_multi_col
alter table test_supTable
    add constraint UK_multi_col unique (colOne, colTwo)
```

db tables:

```
| test_subtable | CREATE TABLE `test_subtable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `colOne` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colTwo` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colThree` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_multi_col` (`colOne`,`colTwo`,`colThree`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_a5tjgjgpmww7otw30iyvmym1m` (`colOne`,`colTwo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

| test_suptable | CREATE TABLE `test_suptable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `colOne` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colTwo` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_multi_col` (`colOne`,`colTwo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Is this a hibernate bug??

Answer (score 0):

After a day of searching and testing it looks like its a Hibernate bug, testing with EclipseLink produces the correct db mapping. I have submitted a bug report to hibernate

see: [HHH-14234](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14234) for test cases, EclipseLink project files, and issue status.

If anyone comes across a good solution to the issue please post.

UPDATE:
looks like the bug has been fixed, see:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/3574

UPDATE:
this issue will be fixed in Hibernate version 5.5.0